# Query to get content older than 3 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My content table looks like (`contentID`, `title`, `created`).  I need to get all content that was created more than 3 weeks ago.

Using a SQL Server database and `created` is of `datetime` datatype.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned the database. I am not sure there is a ANSI way of doing this.

Comment: created is of datetime type, sql server db.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

How about:

```
select contentID, title, created 
from content
where created < dateadd(week,-3,getdate());
```

This sticks closer to the question. 21 days is fine, obviously means the same, but I find that it's good to use the terminology used in the question.

For example... a while back I was asked to survey an average of 1 in 50 visitors to a site. I described this as a proportion of 0.02, and the client wasn't happy. I pointed out to the client that they're the same, but I learned my lesson, and now if I change the way that something is described, I make sure I comment to that effect, and preferably don't change it in the first place. If the client wants 3 weeks, do it as 3 weeks, not 21 days.

Comment: +1 And when they want to change it to 4 weeks, they don't want to do the math (I guess that's why we have computers and programmers.).

Comment: Will this get the date which are WEEK days instead of also including the weekend?

Comment: Yes. This code doesn't care about which days of the week things occur - it simply says "anything before three weeks earlier than now."

Comment: dateadd() with positive and negative intervals and the ability to calculate for days, weeks, etc., is very versatile solution.  Has simplified my tasks countless times.

Answer (score 4):

in MS SQl 2000/2005 you can do this

```
Select
   contactID,
   title,
   created
from
   content
where
   created < getdate()-21
```

Comment: You should try to stay away from implicit "dateadd(day)" math.  Why?  The new DATE data types in SQL Server 2008 will not like the + or - operators (there will be a type clash error).  I used GETDATE()+-INT for a long time and am treaking to break the habit myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select contentID, title, created from content
where created < dateadd(day,-21,getdate())
```

Comment: How can I use this method for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021347/how-to-get-two-week-prior-data-from-a-table